# How to force a redraw in JS for CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, css

Since in 2019, we STILL don't have a working transition from `height: auto` to a fixed height in CSS, I need to set my height manually via JS.

I would like to set the height, force a "redraw" (that essentially does nothing in the eyes of the user), and then set the height to 0 and have the transition work, all within the SAME function.

I would very much like to avoid a hacky `setTimeout(functionThatSetsHeightToZero, 1)`.

Here is the code:

```
    /* e = a plus/minus ui element */
    function toggleBox(e) {
        var box = document.querySelector(".box table");
        if(e.innerHTML == "-") {
            if(!(box.getAttribute("data-height") > 0)) {
                box.setAttribute("data-height", box.getBoundingClientRect().height);
                box.style.height = box.getAttribute("data-height")+"px";
                /* INSERT WAY TO FORCE REDRAW HERE */
            } 
            box.style.height = "0";
            e.innerHTML = "+";
        }
        else {
            box.style.height = box.getAttribute("data-height")+"px";
            e.innerHTML = "-";
        }
   }
```

CSS:

```
.box table {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    transition: height 0.2s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

EDIT:

Actually, the hacky solution doesn't work either, until I set the timeout high enough. A value of 100ms for example isn't enough for the browser to update and animate the first closing transition. 1000ms works.

Unfortunately, the `console.log(box.offsetHeight);` tip doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Doesn't `zoom` force a redraw?

Comment: `box.offsetTop;` does the trick. Retrieving the position of an element after the DOM was changed forces a re-calculation of the DOM, and that's enough to update the values for the transition.